# Jquery click function not working

Tags: jquery

jQuery is not working with the pop-up div.  What happens is when i click on any of the `Click Me` text, the pop-up div is shown.  Then i click on either `one` or `two` and nothing happens!?  If i click on `one`, `two` should disappear and vice versa.

Copy the code below and try for yourself.  What's the solution?

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ratecontainer {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:40px;

    }
    .ratecontainer a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;

    }

    .ratebutton1 {
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#59758d;
    }

    .ratebutton1:hover {
    background-color:#4a6f8e;

    }
    .ratebutton2 {
    padding:5px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#59758d;
    }

    .ratebutton2:hover {
    background-color:#4a6f8e;

    }

    #info {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    width:950px;
    height:auto;
    top:100px;
    left:50%;
    z-index:20;
    margin-left:-475px;

    border:1px solid #000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    display: none;


    }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('.ratebutton1').click(function() {

            $('.ratebutton2').hide();

        });

        $('.ratebutton2').click(function() {

            $('.ratebutton1').hide();

        });

          $('.infobutton').click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
var row = '#box'+id;

$('#info').css('display','block');
var ninfo = $(row).html();
$('#info').html(ninfo);
});

    });



    </script>

     <div id="info"></div>


<div class="menucontainer"><a id="0" class='infobutton'>Click Me </a></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="box0">

    <div class="ratecontainer">
        <form  action="">
            <a class="ratebutton1">One</a><a class="ratebutton2">two</a>
        </form>
    </div>



</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P4KYL/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a stub fiddle for your code: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/P4KYL/

Edit it removing any php-related cruft (and manually put multiple items where necessary)

Then post the edited version back and I'll check what's wrong with it.

Comment: I've edited it, i don't know if the popup works on Jsfiddle but the popup works when i test it.

Comment: it would work if you give me a link to the hosted plugin (infobox)

BTW, I suggest you try changing `click` to `live`. I can suppose your infobox is cloning the element rather than re-parenting it. In this cases event handlers wouldn't copy

Answer (score -2):

```
    $('.ratebutton1').click(function() {

        $('.ratebutton2').hide();

    });
```

Right here is one issue I believe. Your buttons are not named .ratebutton1 but rather ratebutton1. Take out the period and try it. Hope it helps

Comment: the period defines it is a class.   $('ratebutton2').hide(); wouldn't work.